# Tkinter: Data formation in my_tree is wrong after closing the app

Tags: python, tkinter

I want that the data which is added looks the same in my_tree after closing and opening the appication.

As you see when i added Michael it is shown correct but when i reopen the app then it gets strange like you see it in the other examples where lastname becomes a comma and quotation marks are added.

```
# create table in database
table_name = 'StudData'
schema = 'dbo'
columns = [
    ('stud_id', 'INT', 'PRIMARY KEY' ),
    ('firstname', 'CHAR(50)', 'NOT NULL'),
    ('lastname', 'CHAR(50)', 'NOT NULL'),
    ('adress', 'VARCHAR(100)', 'NOT NULL')
]

#check if table exists
cursor.execute(f"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = '{table_name}'")
table_exists = cursor.fetchone()[0]

#build the create table query
if not table_exists:
    query = f"CREATE TABLE {schema}.{table_name} ("
    for column in columns:
     column_name, data_type, constraints = column
     query += f"{column_name} {data_type} {constraints}, "
    query = query.rstrip(', ') + ")"
    cursor.execute(query)
    conn.commit()
    print(f"Table '{table_name}' created succesfully.")
else:
    print(f"Table '{table_name}' already exists.")

#execute




def add_data():
  studid = studId_textbox.get()
  fname = firstname_textbox.get()
  lname = lastname_textbox.get()
  adress = address_textbox.get()

  if studid.strip() == "" or fname.strip() == "" or lname.strip() == "" or adress.strip() == "":
      messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Please fill up all the fields!")

  else:
      try:
          studid = int(studid)
          query = f"INSERT INTO {table_name}  (stud_id, firstname, lastname, adress) VALUES ( ?, ? ,? ,?) "
          cursor.execute(query, (studid, fname , lname, adress))
          conn.commit()
          messagebox.showinfo("Data added succesfully!")

          #insert data into my_tree
          my_tree.insert("", "end" , values=(studid, fname, lname, adress))


      except Exception as e:
          messagebox.showinfo("Error", f"Failed to add data: {str(e)}")





def del_data():
    select_data = my_tree.focus()

    if select_data:
        values = my_tree.item(select_data)['values']
        stud_id = int(values[0])
        query = f"DELETE FROM {table_name} WHERE stud_id = ?"
        cursor.execute(query, (stud_id,))
        conn.commit()

        my_tree.delete(select_data)



def load_data():
    query = f"SELECT stud_id, firstname, lastname, adress FROM {table_name}"
    cursor.execute(query)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        studid, fname, lname, adress = row
        my_tree.insert("", "end", values=row)
```

Comment: What is `my_tree`? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Where/how is `my_tree` defined? I assume it's a `ttk.Treeview`, but you should [edit] your question to include the relevant info